# Showing an image in Cakephp 2.3

Tags: php, image, cakephp, image-processing, cakephp-2.3

I'm coding a small news component for a website using cakephp. The ideal way in which this would work is by letting the administrator input the title for the news item, the source, the link to it (if available), its contents (to have a back up) and an accompanying image for it.

It all works but the image part. Since every entry is meant to have at most ONE image, I'm storing the image info in the same database table I'm storing the posts. I have so far managed to upload the image file to app/uploads/ and add its data (name, size and type) to the database.

Now I can't show it.

All I have managed to do looking around is set the image to be the single content of a page by using:

```
$this->response->file($url);
```

However, I need to be able to show this image as an embedded part of a website, just as most images in the web are shown. I've been looking around and can't seem to find any proper guides on doing this. The simplest solution (Linking to the image by knowing the path to the images folder) also won't work since they are in app/uploads, meaning that if I link there cakephp thinks I'm calling an 'uploads' class that doesn't exist. Using MOD_REWRITE could be an option but, in all honesty, it seems to me it would be more of a hack since there has to be a way to take a stored file and dump it as an image so that it can be embedded on the very site that's storing it.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: putting the images in `app/webroot/uploads` isn't an option?

Comment: I've thought about that (putting them outside the cake folder) but it's a bit of the same - Cakephp should have a way to do this without resorting to such tricks, and ideally I'd want all files having to do with the cake application inside its folder.

By the way, by app/whatever I mean the app folder where the cakephp program is running (That is, already in the web server), not a relative address to my pc.

Comment: `your-cake-folder/app/webroot/uploads` will be inside the cake folder (`webroot` is the folder where all files needed to be public accessed are stored, like css and js), it complies with what you asked. I wouldn't advice storing the images outside cake for this matter.

Comment: Well I feel rather stupid now, that worked just fine. Funny thing I have been getting info from cakephp tutorials here and there for a week and can't recall having ever read about the webroot folder. Thanks a lot!

(By the way, how do I mark your post as an answer?)

Comment: I haven't post anything, I've just commented. I'll post an answer now with what we've talked so you can mark it (there will be a check mark beside my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things that need to have public access for visualization, like css or js files... or in this case images, the easy option is to put it in the `webroot` folder.

The usual structure I have with cake is like

```
/app
   /Config
   ....
   /webroot
      /js
      /cs
      /users
         /images
         /docs
         ...etc
```

Trying to access a folder in app (like `app/uploads`) will cause problems with the routing of controllers and views. So it's easier to keep things inside `webroot`. Specially if it's images strictly related with cake only.

Keep in mind that things in webroot *have* public access, so don't keep files in there that you don't want to be accessed by url.

Comment: Thanks again! It was a very small thing, but it was doing my head in. Didn't help that the tutorials I followed didn't state that anywhere :)